# ( AngularJS + Passport ) User authentication

Tags: javascript, angularjs, passport.js, mean-stack, passport-local

I am new to Passport and I send email and password as {"email":"gg@gmail.com","password":"xxx"} as request body to the server.On server side,I make use of passportJS as in https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local#available-options like,

```
   passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    {usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
  },
    function(req,username,password,done){
      console.log("am here");
      var x=req.body;
      var email=x.email;
      var password=x.password;
      console.log(x.email);

}
))

app.post('/loginUser',passport.authenticate('local'),function(req,res){
   var x=req.body;
   db.users.findOne({"email":x.email,"password":x.password},function(err,user){
     res.json(user)
   })

 });
```

The Local Strategy isn't getting accessed.The application crashes and I only get TypeError: LocalStrategy requires a verify callback. Please let me know where i went wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LocalStrategy includes optional `options` where you specify the parameters in the POST body passed to the server (the default parameters looked for are `username` and `password`).

Just specify your parameters you're passing in your POST body here, as provided in the documentation: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local#available-options

Comment: That was indeed a good suggestion Lance , but still I get the same Type Error. I have updated the question on the same. Please let me know where i went wrong.

Comment: Hi..mistake was on my side with respect to importing package. THanks for your response.